# How to display the total amount of products and the total amount of configurable products in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to write a script that display 
1) the total amount of products, 
2) the total amount of configurable products, 
3) the total amount of products within the attribute set "None", 
4) the total amount of orders, and 
5) the total amount $ of orders within a certain time range in Magento.

I've solved the 4) and 5), but have problems finding out the solutions for 1) 2) and 3). Can anyone help?

---------------------------After 2/3/2015 ---------------------------

Here is the modified version of the code with the help of @Blastfreak, the problem with this code is that it display the wrong amount of configurable products and "None" products - looks like the total amount has been displayed regardless:

```
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$collection = $productModel->getCollection();
//Attribute Set "None" and "NONE"
$attributeSetId_None1 = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
    ->load($attrSetName, 'None')
    ->getAttributeSetId();    
$attributeSetId_NONE2 = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
    ->load($attrSetName, 'NONE')
    ->getAttributeSetId();
//1) Total Products
$TotalProducts = $collection->getSize();

//2) Configurable Products

$TotalConfigurableProduct= $collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'))->getSize();

//3) Total Productw within attribute set none
if ($attributeSetId_None1 || $attributeSetId_NONE2){
$Total_None1= $collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id',$attributeSetId_None1)->getSize();
$Total_NONE2= $collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id',$attributeSetId_NONE2)->getSize();
$TotalNone=$Total_None1+$Total_NONE2;
}
else{
$TotalNone=0;
}

$TotalConfigurableAndNone=$TotalConfigurableProduct+$TotalNone;
```

---

Instead of using getSize() or count(), I found that the foreach loop can display the correct amount of items. For example:

```
foreach ($TotalConfigurableProduct as $total_config)
{
    $k++; //the correct amount of configurable products
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Solution for following :

```
<?php 

$productModel = Mage::geModel('catalog/product');
$collection = $productModel->getCollection;

//1) Total Products
$TotalProducts = $collection->getSize();

//2) Configurable Products

$TotalConfigurableProduct= $collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'))->getSize();

//3) Total Productw within attribute set none

$TotalConfigurableProduct= $collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id','attribute set id here')->getSize();
```

Comment: Thank you so much Blastfreak! I've edited the question.